# React-native project on expo then on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, react-native, expo

I don't understand the transition from Expo project to Android Studio.
I ejected my react-native app using expo and now im trying to run it on Android-Studio.

Do i still code in Javascript after the eject ?
What are the files in new Android folder corresponding to the Components i created in my expo project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do an `expo eject`, you need to be able to manage Android and iOS manually.

Unlike `react-native` in the Android folder, there is an additional `expo-package`.

The usage is the same as the old `react-native`.

Just fill out the `JavaScript code` as you used to.

The difference is that the '`react-native`' module is available. Modules requiring `react-native link`

[this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios) is about `react-native link`

You can make your own module and apply it.

[this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup) is about `react-native create module`

Comment: So i don't need Android Studio or XCode after the expo eject ?

Comment: And how can i test the application after expo eject ?

Comment: Whether you're doing an "expo eject" or not, you need both Andriodisudio and Xcode for a run expo-code.

Comment: If you just do an "expo eject," you have to do an "expo start" and a Android studio if it's Android, and if it's an iPhone, you have to run an Xcode.